# How do you protect your online identity from background checks?

Tags: privacy, information-gathering

This site is the only piece of online presence I have in my own name. I also have two gmail addresses in my own name.

If a background check is to be made on my online activities, would there be a way to protect all my online data except this site from a search?

I have never done anything illegal but I would still prefer all of it to remain private.

I operate under pseudonyms for everything except email and this site but I wonder if even anonymous content could be traced back to me?

This is in regards to potential employers, not the government checks. This is also not meant to cover any illegal activity. It is more to cover the fact that I have had the same youtube account since 2007 and I probably said some pretty stupid stuff on it over the years.

Comment: With enough effort, content you posted under synonyms can be traced back to you. The question is whether or not a potential employer will do more than google your name.

Comment: I would love for you to expand on that premise Luca when you get the chance. What efforts could be used to make that effort more would also be useful.

Comment: If your potential employer cares about what you said back then and will use it as the grounds to turn your resume down you as well be happy. Not only it's called digging in the dirt, it's just hugely unethical and I'd steer clear of them.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no "one-size-fits-all" solution.

How easy or difficult it is to track something back to you depends entirely on your behavior online. How much do you post in your real name? Do you use your e-mail addresses to sign up for anything? Do you use a pseudonymous email address together with your real name somewhere?

All it takes is one slip up to leave behind evidence that "xXx_DudeBro69_xXx" and "Neil Meyer" are the same person.

It also depends on how interested a potential party is in finding a connection. In the comments, you mentioned an employer. From personal experience, most employers will look at social media sites and see if they can find you and what kind of stuff you post. For example, "objectionable" political opinions, pictures of you getting drunk and puking on the floor, etc.. The goal here is to ensure you won't harm the company's public image.

It'd be *very* unusual for a potential employer to attempt to find every possible pseudonymous account someone uses online, and to be honest, if my employer did, I would look for a new job.

---

In short, how likely it is for a pseudonymous account to remain untied to your real identity depends on how separate you keep them, and how eager a potential party is in finding said account and linking it to you.